# how to copy just first 4 columns on a loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy from a spreadsheet to another using a few parts of a code found here, however after making some adjustments I am running into an issue where after copying the values from `sheet1` to `sheet2` it is copying all 2000 columns when I just need it to copy the first 4 columns, also I need to copy everything under ('TC1')

note that TC1 will be listed 3 times on each worksheet.

1) I am having in resume is that I want just to copy first 4 columns
2) there are 2 spaces or more between the end of TC1 and the next one listed on Column(1)
3) it is just copying the first few rows instead of the whole list before Lastrow of reach TC1

```
    'VBA Open excel to copy TC to master list Dir
Sub Copy_Paste__To_New_Sheet()

    'Variable Declaration
    Dim sFilePath As String
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim rngCopy As Range, acell As Range, bcell As Range
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim strFile As Variant
    Dim wb2 As Excel.Workbook


    'Specify File Path
    sFilePath = "C:\temp\new"

    'Check for back slash
    If Right(sFilePath, 1) <> "\" Then
        sFilePath = sFilePath & "\"
    End If

    sFileName = Dir(sFilePath)

    Do While Len(sFileName) > 0
    Set rngCopy = Nothing
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sFilePath & sFileName)
        Sheets("TestCases").Activate
'        Range("E:E").Insert
        'Display file name in immediate window
'        Debug.Print sFileName
        strSearch = "TC1"

    Set WS = Worksheets("TestCases")

    With WS
        Set acell = .Columns(1).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not acell Is Nothing Then
            Set bcell = acell

            If rngCopy Is Nothing Then
                Set rngCopy = WS.Range(WS.Cells(acell.Row + 1, 1), WS.Cells(acell.Row + 2, 4))
            Else
                Set rngCopy = Application.Union(rngCopy, .Rows((acell.Row + 1) & ":" & (acell.Row + 2)))
            End If

            Do
                Set acell = .Columns(1).FindNext(After:=acell)

                If Not acell Is Nothing Then
                    If acell.Address = bcell.Address Then Exit Do

                    If rngCopy Is Nothing Then
                        Set rngCopy = WS.Range(WS.Cells(acell.Row + 1, 1), WS.Cells(acell.Row + 2, 4))
                    Else
                        Set rngCopy = Application.Union(rngCopy, .Rows((acell.Row + 1) & ":" & (acell.Row + 2)))
                    End If
                Else
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Loop
        Else
            MsgBox SearchString & " not Found"
        End If

        '~~> I am pasting to Output sheet. Change as applicable

            Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\temp\output\outputtest.xlsx")
            If Not rngCopy Is Nothing Then Sheets("Output").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(rngCopy.Rows.Count, 4).Value = rngCopy.Value

'            If Not rngCopy Is Nothing Then Sheets("Output").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 4).Value = rngCopy.Value
'        If Not rngCopy Is Nothing Then rngCopy.Copy Sheets("Output").Cells(1, 1).Resize(rngCopy.Rows.Count, rngCopy.Columns.Count)
'        .End (xlDown) + 1
'        Sheets("Output").Rows(1)
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        wb2.Close savechanges = False

    End With
```

[image: Source Data]
[image: Destination]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set `rngCopy` to be the entire row everytime. This means it will copy all the columns of that row. Instead, you need to set `rngCopy` to only include the first 4 columns. You can do that with something like this

```
Set rngCopy = WS.Range(WS.Cells(acell.Row + 1, 1), WS.Cells(acell.Row + 2, 4))
```

instead of

```
Set rngCopy = .Rows((acell.Row + 1) & ":" & (acell.Row + 2))
```

Comment: Thank you @ Alex de Jong, I see my error now
but  I am now getting a Run-Time error 1004, This action won't work on multiple selections.

Comment: Have you done it for all the different places where you set rngCopy? I guess you get this error at the `Union` function because you try to combine a whole row with a couple of cells.

Comment: you are correct, I am getting it here 'If Not rngCopy Is Nothing Then rngCopy.Copy Sheets("Output").Rows(1)'

Comment: You have to copy rngCopy to `Sheets("Output").Cells(1,1).Resize(rngCopy.row.count,rngCopy.Columns.count)` so that the two ranges match in size.

Comment: sorry to ask, can you guide on how about editing that line, i keep on getting errors, it says invalid qualifier

Comment: Sorry I made a typo. it needs to be `rngCopy.rowS.count` instead of `rngCopy.row.count`.

Comment: so If I do <If Not rngCopy Is Nothing Then rngCopy.Copy Sheets("Output").Cells(1, 1).Resize(rngCopy.Rows.Count, rngCopy.Columns.Count)> I get the same 1004 This action error

Comment: Are you copying one row at a time with rngCopy? In that case you should also be able to use `If  Not rngCopy is nothing then Sheets("Output").cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).offset(1,0).Resize(1,4).value = rngCopy.value`

Comment: so I want to copy as many rows has each TC has before the next empty row, the last part of code you sent, yes it will just copy the last row and will go to the next sheet, I would want to loop before those TC on each sheet paste them to another sheet before looping again. sorry if I am not making it very clear also I am not so good at vba just yet. I appreciate your patience on this

Comment: Allright, so rngCopy exists of multiple rows. In that case: `rngCopy is nothing then Sheets("Output").cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).offset(1,0).Resize(rngCopy.Rows.Count,4).value = rngCopy.value`

Comment: Sorry Alex, Still only doing the first row before the blank, on my original code before we added (4) it was doing every TC listed on the source workbook

Comment: Can you see how many rows rngCopy has? Because if that only has one row, you haven't replaced the code somewhere correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195654/discussion-between-spock-and-alex-de-jong).